# How to scan initial spaces in C

Tags: c, string

I have a typical question it's not that how can I scan spaces using **scanf** but how to scan the initial spaces entered in a string

This is what I've done:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
       int n;
       char a[10];
       scanf("%d",&n);
       scanf(" %[^\n]",a);
       printf("%d",strlen(a));
       return 0;
     }
```

and when I run the program with following input:

> ```
>    aa bb//note there are two spaces before initial a
> ```

and the output is `6` but there are 8 characters i.e, 2 `spaces` followed by 2 `a`'s followed by 2 `spaces` and then lastly 2 `b`'s

I eve tried an own function.. but alas! the length is `6`. Here's my function:

```
int len(char a[101])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;a[i];i++);
    return i;
}
```

**What I think is that the initial 2 spaces are being ignored...or I might be wrong. It'd be great if someone could explain why the length of string is `6` and how can I make it `8` or accept all the `8` characters I mentioned above.**

EDIT: this is my actual code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,N,j,k;
    char **ans,s[101];

    scanf("%d",&N);
    ans=(char **)calloc(N,sizeof(char*));

    for(j=0,i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %[^\n]",s);
        printf("%d",strlen(s));
        ans[i]=(char*)calloc(strlen(s),sizeof(char));
        for(k=0,j=((strlen(s)/2)-1);j>=0;j--,k++)
        {
            ans[i][k]=s[j];
        }
        for(j=strlen(s)-1;j>=strlen(s)/2;k++,j--)
        {
            ans[i][k]=s[j];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",ans[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d",&i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can not use a regex like expression e.g. `"%[^\n]"` within your `scanf`

Comment: @cwschmidt Yes. You can.

Comment: Your code should work as expected. Are you sure you can reproduce this? BTW, your input consist of 7 characters, not 8.

Comment: @Cool Guy AFAIK it only has support to [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) not complete regex expressions.

Comment: @cwschmidt Yes. There is no complete regex support, but `%[^\n]` is valid.

Comment: Your program works fine for me (after I fixed the printf format to `"%zd\n"`). This suggests that you either mistyped the program or your input is not what you think it is.

Comment: Is the above the _true_ code in which you are entering `2 spaces "aa" 2 spaces  "bb"`?

Comment: @chux yes that is what i'm entering

Comment: @ch3rub7 Not asking about what you are entering, asking if the code posted here is **exactly** the same as the code you are compiling and running? as in `#include <stdio.h> ... printf("%d",strlen(a));     return 0;
     }`

Comment: @rici Isn't the right format specifier `%zu`?

Comment: yes.. `scanf(" %[^\n]",a); printf("%d",strlen(a)); ` this is what I've written in my code

Comment: @ch3rub7 Remove the space before `%[^\n]`

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]",a);` (from your comment)  is not the same as the posted code of `scanf("%[^\n]",a);`!  (space vs no-space)

Comment: @chux oh yes space exists... sorry about that

Comment: @CoolGuy: True. Anyway, voting to close as a typo (and consequently a waste of everyone's time.)

Comment: @rici but the problem still persists

Comment: @CoolGuy after scanning an integer I follow the same code but now I get 6... I think problem starts then

Comment: @ch3rub7: The problem is the fact that you ask `scanf` to skip leading spaces, and then you complain when it does that.

Comment: @rici now I get it...but if I avoid space... garbage gets printed

Comment: @ch3rub7: That's a completely different question. You seem to want to use SO as an interactive debugging session, where you post random buggy code, attract answers which may or may not help you, and then modify the question to present completely new bugs, rendering the previous answers irrelevant. That's not what SO is about (imho) and it is not the way to learn how to debug, either. Start by reading `man scanf` and thinking through what happens with each call.

Comment: ah! thanks @rici figured it out... I've used get char to take in '\n' and now code works fine .... thank you all

Comment: @rici sorry about it! I've thought about not posting and I know it's my fault to not to know the workings of functions better.... surely next time I'll not post such questions.. anyway thanks for your enlightment

Comment: @rici Agreed. I've also voted to close. But why does [`%zd` give out no warning](http://rextester.com/ESPLN5741)?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Excellent question. With gcc-5, you can supply `-Wformat-signedness` to get that warning, but I don't see a way to get it with gcc-4.9. I suppose gcc knows that it's not a fatal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP code *should* work as posted.

OP comments true code is using `scanf(" %[^\n]",a);` which fully explains the problem: the space in the format is consuming leading white-space.

To address other issues with `scanf()`, see following.

---

`fgets()` is the right tool.

Yet if OP insists on `scanf()`

> how can I scan spaces using scanf but how to scan the initial spaces entered in a string?

```
char buf[100];

// Scan up to 99 non\n characters and form a string in `buf`
switch (scanf("%99[^\n]", buf)) {
  case 0: buf[0] = '\0'; break;   // line begins with `'\n`

  //  May want to check if strlen(buf)==99 to detect a long line
  case 1: break;                  // Success.

  case EOF: buf[0] = '\0'; break; // stdin is closed.
}
fgetc(stdin); // throw away the \n still in stdin.
```

Comment: ya even when I tried on ideone... it gives me 8, but when I run it on my eclipse IDE it gives 6

Comment: @ch3rub7 "when I run it", is the "it" the posted code or something close it "it"?

Comment: actually it's a part of a larger program that I've written should I paste it in question?

Comment: @ch3rub7 I am certain that other parts of your code are consuming the leading spaces.  Report the code that involved the previous input.

Comment: I've added simply what happens in the code... first I scan an integer and then the string

Answer (score 1):

The issue i believe is that you need to be getting length from a Pointer to the array not the array itself. 
Try this, this code worked for me.

```
int ArrayLength(char* stringArray) 
{
   return strlen(stringArray);
}
```

Comment: @CoolGuy sorry about that, mixed up my languages. fixed for c.

Comment: Why not use `strlen` directly?

Comment: Because if you don't deference it you are getting length of an address i believe.

Comment: Oh sorry I missunderstood, thought you were asking about why the `char*`. You mean why not just call `strlen(a)`? And there may be a good reason for it but that's just how i wrote the code.

Comment: Nope bro it didn't work I'm using eclipse Ide... Is it any issue with my ide?

Comment: I think it might be. I tried running your code as given on Ideoone.com and given the string "  aa  bb" 2 spaces before a and 2 before b returns the desired 8. My code works fine there also.

Comment: ya even I tried... and even I tried running exe file generated but it too gives 6

Comment: That's odd. I tried running it on the online compiler at https://www.remoteinterview.io/online-c-compiler and once again it gives 8.

Comment: actually it's a part of a larger program should I paste it in question?

Comment: ya I've and... now the problem is even apparent on ideone.... i'm scanning an int before string

Comment: thanks man... I've figured my mistake... silly one. nothing to bother about... anyway thanks once again

Comment: Yea I noticed. Glad you were able to solve the issue.